# R unlist grouped data frame

Tags: r, vector, igraph

I have a dataset like below

```
Employee    address
E1          A1
E2          A2
E3          A1
E4          A1
E5          A3
```

I need to create relation between employees which reside on same address so I can create a graph edge (igraph)

```
E1 E3 E1 E4
```

I used group by Address which give me correct grouped result but not sure how to get the desired vector

```
as.vector(data %>% group_by(address) %>% select(employee))
```

Comment: What exactly is your expected output?

Comment: Expected output is E1,E3,E1,E4 in vector

Comment: Why does `E1` appear twice?

Comment: I don't see the logic then.. Thinking in terms of edges I could imagine E1<->E3, E1<->E4, but then also E3<->E4.

Comment: Yes. We will have to do E3,E4 as well I guess. I do not see logic how it can be done otherwise

Comment: If you are going to use `igraph`, then perhaps `tcrossprod(table(data)) - diag(nrow(data))` gives all you need? A corresponding adjacency matrix.

Comment: I get bellow error when running the code you suggested -> Error in table(dd) - diag(nrow(dd)) : non-conformable arrays

Comment: I also have `tcrossprod` in my code.

Comment: Sorry. That compiled but how do I plot the graph now with iGraph in R with this data?

Comment: I posted a complete answer, perhaps that's what you are after.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187342/discussion-between-ankit-and-julius-vainora).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to get an undirected graph from this. It could be done as follows.

```
library(igraph)
g <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(tcrossprod(table(data)) - diag(nrow(data)), mode = "undirected")
plot(g)
```

[image]